# Setting the selected value of a ListBoxView as a string (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, string

When a value is selected in a ListBoxView, How could the selection be stored as a string / variable, so I can then call another method that will use this string to perform an action?

Comment: There is no listboxview control. What are you using listview or listbox?

Comment: @Reniuz Sorry, its a listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Items in your listbox are all strings, you could use

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lb= new ListBox();
            lb.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Otherwise, we will need to know the types of items you have added to the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you using ListBox get selected item like this:

```
string item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

If you using ListView get selected item(s) depending on MultiSelect property:

1. Use this code if MultiSelect property = false

   ```
   string itemName = listView.SelectedItems[0].Name;
   ```
2. Use this code if MultiSelect property = true

   ```
   foreach (ListViewItem item in ltvMainMenu.SelectedItems)
   {
      string itemName = item.Name;    
   }
   ```